Do we want our site to be part of the Winter Bash 2016?
Season’s greetings, crypto freaks and geeks!
The year is rapidly coming to a close, which means it’s time to have some fun... with hats! That’s right - it’s time for Winter Bash 2016!
Winter... what?
Winter Bash - a yearly event where users can win (digital) hats for achieving specific goals. It's somewhat like the regular badges you can earn at every SE site but with a more creative twist which ranges up to a ranking where all participating SE sites compete with each other to see which one is able to grab the most hats.
To get an idea of what this might look like, take a look at the previous winterbash events. As an example, here's looking back at 2015...


Details
This year, the event will run from 19 December 2016 up to and including 08 January 2017. Users will be able to see all the hats they’ve earned on http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com. That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and other details of the event. 
Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option available. And just like last time, at the end of the event, all hats will go back into storage. 
The only visual change to the Stack Exchange sites themselves will be the presence of the hats and the “I hate hats” button in the footer.
Question
Now, don't ask me why, but stackexchange thinks that some communities may not want this kind of event on their sites at all and is asking us if we want to completely opt-out or not. Since this is a community thing, the Crypto.SE users should decide for themselves... do we want our site to be part of the Winter Bash 2016?
For your convenience, I added two apperopriate answers so all you need to do is upvote what you prefer.
Remember, this is not asking if you personally want to participate or not; this question asks if we should opt-out as a whole - the complete Crypto.SE community (aka "all users").
Deadline
If we - as a community - want to completely opt-out, we have to contact the SE team no later than 13 December 2016. To be sure that deadline is kept, I will accept the most-upvoted answer around and about 23:59 UTC on Sunday, 11 December 2016 and forward the community-voted decision.
Thanks for your attention and your vote(s)!

If we opt-out as a community, is it a complete and total opt-out (ie nobody can ever opt-in) or a personal opt-in (ie you need to get active to opt-in as opposed to before where you had to be active to opt-out)?

@SEJPM First is correct. Opting out would mean Crypto.SE would not be part of the Winter Bash 2016. No hats, no bash listing of Crypto.SE, nada. At our site, things would be as if Winter Bash wouldn't exist... while other sites can also decide for themselves if they participate or not (and consequently they'll show hats et all, or not).

I'm all for hats! Reading this as a SE newbie it wasn't immediately clear what it was about, perhaps add a link to older iterations (e.g. http://stackpromos.com/promos) so we know what we're voting for? Also sensing a slight bias towards one of the options :-)

@CurveEnthusiast Edited that in. Thanks for the heads-up!

Yes, gimme hats!
I think Crypto.SE - as a community - should participate in the winter bash 2016.
Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option available.

Winter hats were the sole purpose of this site, right?

Oh, heck, if it gets participation to this site up for the off hours (heh, I have access to the stats now) I'm all for it. Seems most of us visit during office hours. What's a good family dinner with turkey worth in the end :P

No way!
I think Crypto.SE - as a community - should completely opt-out of participating in the winter bash 2016.
Not a single user of our community should be bothered with something annoying like that. I mean, hats? No one needs hats.
